# Alorithm to find line segments closest to the X-Axis

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stack

[image]

We have a list of line segments (intervals) :
input Array of objects in the following order:

```
// Start and end represents the x coordinate and distance represents the y coordinate.
{start: 13, end: 15, distance: 1}, // S[0] -- pale red
{start: 12, end: 15, distance: 2}, // S[1] -- pale orange
{start: 2, end: 5, distance: 1}, // S[2] -- pale yellow
{start: 7, end: 9, distance: 2}, // S[3] -- pale green 1
{start: 7, end: 9, distance: 2}, // S[4] -- pale green 2
{start: 6, end: 8, distance: 2}, // S[5] -- fresh green
{start: 2, end: 5, distance: 4}, // S[6] -- pale gray
{start: 5, end: 11, distance: 4}, // S[7] -- air blue
{start: 9, end: 10, distance: 1}, // S[8] -- cyan blue
{start: 1, end: 11, distance: 3}, // S[9] -- magenta purple
```

We want to find the parts of each of intervals closest to x axis:

```
{start: 1, end: 2, in: S[9]},
{start: 2, end: 5, in: S[2]},
{start: 5, end: 6, in: S[9]},
{start: 6, end: 8, in: S[5]},
{start: 8, end: 9, in: S[3]},
{start: 9, end: 10, in: S[8]},
{start: 10, end: 11, in: S[9]},
{start: 12, end: 13, in: S[1]},
{start: 13, end: 15, in: S[0]},
```

One way of achieving this is

1. First sorting the array of objects.
2. Then using N no. of Stacks to push each interval and keep the one which is closest to x axis (lowest distance) and creating the final set.

But this wont be the optimal one.
What should be the optimal solution for this?